# How to store a file on a server(web container) through a Java EE web application?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee, file-storage

I have developed a Java EE web application. This application allows a user to upload a file with the help of a browser. Once the user has uploaded his file, this application first stores the uploaded file on the server (on which it is running) and then processes it.

At present, I am storing the file on the server as follows:

```
try {
    // formFile represents the uploaded file
    FormFile formFile = programForm.getTheFile();
    String path = getServlet().getServletContext().getRealPath("") + "/"
        + formFile.getFileName();
    System.out.println(path);
    file = new File(path);
    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    outputStream.write(formFile.getFileData());
}
```

where, the `formFile` represents the uploaded file.

Now, the problem is that it is running fine on some servers but on some servers the `getServlet().getServletContext().getRealPath("")` is returning `null` so the final path that I am getting is `null/filename` and the file doesn't store on the server.

When I checked the API for [`ServletContext.getRealPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29) method, I found the following:

> `public java.lang.String getRealPath(java.lang.String path)`
>
> Returns a String containing the real path for a given virtual path. For example, the path `"/index.html"` returns the absolute file path on the server's filesystem would be served by a request for `"http://host/contextPath/index.html"`, where contextPath is the context path of this ServletContext.
>
> The real path returned will be in a form appropriate to the computer and operating system on which the servlet container is running, including the proper path separators. This method returns null if the servlet container cannot translate the virtual path to a real path for any reason (such as when the content is being made available from a .war archive).

So, Is there any other way by which I can store files on those servers also which is returning `null` for `getServlet().getServletContext().getRealPath("")`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Writing to the file system from a Java EE container is not really recommended, especially if you need to process the written data:

- it is not transactional
- it harms the portability (what if you are in a clustered environment)
- it requires to setup external parameters for the target location

If this is an option, I would store the files in database or use a JCR repository (like [Jackrabbit](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/)).

Comment: @Pascal I want to store only a single file to be processed later. So I think that it would not be a good idea to store that file in the database? What do you think? The file is a .csv file. If you think that I should store it in the database, then should I store it in byte forms or any other form because the size of the file can be of 100 or 200 MBs. Second, I heard about "Jackrabbit" first time from you and I don't know what it is. I looked at its site but didn't find any tutorial. So could you please tell me which one would be better: using a database or using the "Jackrabbit"?

Comment: @Yatendra I was underlying drawbacks of writing to the file system "for the record". For many applications, this might not be an option at all but is maybe not be a problem for your. Now, to answer your questions... 1) Writing to a database can be done (in a LOB); it's not ideal but if you don't write thousands of files per day, it should be ok. 2) Jackrabbit is an implementation of the JCR API (JSR-170), a standard API to write and store files to a content repository and is thus an alternative. But using a JCR repository sounds overkill for a small application. *I* would use the database.

Comment: I have a similar question, but I need to store small files - so it's a big overhead to use any kind of database which needs separate setup and support. So vote-down for this  answer and vote-up for the @Will Hartung's answer - because it looks for me much more simple for simple problem.

Comment: @Vladimir you _downvote_ a correct answer because you do not want to use a database?  Good luck with your subtle vendor dependencies.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, Why not? This is democracy right? I can down-vote I think answer is not correct - even the question was not about how to organize the file upload, but about technical details. :-) I have no dependencies. I think it's not natural to store files in database that's why filesystem exists. Especially I would avoid using frameworks where it's more elegant to store the uploaded file on disk.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, also note another answer has more votes. This means that the correct answer is only correct for original user :-)

Comment: @Vladimir you do not appear to have noticed that file system access is not part of the Servlet specification.  This mean that regardless how elegant you think are, you are wandering into vendor specific territory.  Also number of upvotes do not reflect correctness.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, It's possible to define server variable like FILE_STORAGE_PATH and store all files here - isn't it? I don't think anyone deploy applications in ideal vendor-less environment. Anyway the choice is done and we don't need to flame anymore on it.

Comment: @Vladimir I do not "flame".  I am pointing out a very real possible cause of error in your application which may be very hard to find when it shows.

Answer (score 21):

By spec, the only "real" path you are guaranteed to get form a servlet container is a temp directory.

You can get that via the `ServletContext.gerAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir")`. However, these files are not visible to the web context (i.e. you can not publish a simple URL to deliver those files), and the files are not guaranteed in any way to survive a web app or server restart.

If you simply need a place to store a working file for a short time, then this will work fine for you.

If you really need a directory, you can make it a configuration parameter (either an environment variable, a Java property (i.e. `java -Dyour.file.here=/tmp/files ...`), a context parameter set in the web.xml, a configuration parameter stored in your database via a web form, etc.). Then it's up to the deployer to set up this directory for you.

However, if you need to actually later serve up that file, you will either need a container specific mechanism to "mount" external directories in to your web app (Glassfish as "alternate doc roots", others have similar concepts), or you will need to write a servlet/filter to serve up file store outside of your web app. This [FileServlet](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/02/fileservlet-supporting-resume-and.html) is quite complete, and as you can see, creating your own, while not difficult, isn't trivial to do it right.

**Edit:**

The basic gist is the same, but rather than using "getRealPath", simply use "getInitParameter".

So:

```
String filePath = getServletContext().getInitParameter("storedFilePath") + "/" + fileName;
```

And be on your way.

**Edit again:**

As for the contents of the path, I'd give it an absolute path. Otherwise, you would need to KNOW where the app server sets its default path to during exeuction, and each app server may well use different directories. For example, I believe the working directory for Glassfish is the config directory of the running domain. Not a particularly obvious choice.

So, use an absolute path, most definitely. That way you KNOW where the files will go, and you can control the access permissions at the OS level for that directory, if that's necessary.

Comment: I need to store the files on a directory that can survive server and web-app restart. From you answer, I would like to make it a configuration parameter by setting a context parameter. But I didn't get how can I store file with that. Can you provide an example or a reference to an example?

Comment: @Will You showed me how to retrieve the value of a context parameter which I know already. May be my comment was not clear. Actually, I meant what value would you give to the "storedFilePath" context parameter. A relative file path or absolute file path?

Comment: If you give a relative path, the how will you convert it into absolute path?

Comment: Note that accessing the file system directly will make you vendor dependent, and possibly fail - especially on multi-host application servers.

Comment: Thank you Will Hartung, your suggestion was very useful for my requirement