# Is there an equivalent to GlassFish "Alternate Document Roots" for Tomcat?

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets, download

Since storing uploaded files in the container of a Java EE web application is not recommended,  I store them in a local directory outside the webroot.

Now I need to serve them to web users. With GlassFish, I know how to do so quite easily, using [Alternate Document Roots](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1752/geqpl/index.html). But I'm working with Tomcat right now, and I can't find a simple way. Is there a similar feature available on this server? Or do I really have to create a [FileServlet](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/02/fileservlet-supporting-resume-and.html) to get the job done? If so, will I encounter performances issue when lots of users access those external files?

Edit: I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2663250/401881) saying that other servers seem to have similar systems, but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Tomcat 7, the [aliases attribute](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Standard_Implementation) might help.